# Replace Strings in a nested Object with values from another file using `string.replace() Method`

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object, str-replace

How can I replace the tokens `__fruit_type__, __clothing_type__, __fitness_equipment__,  __meditation_app__` in collection.js with values from `values.js`?

I am trying to achieve this with the `string.replace() Method`

```
   collection.js
```

```
{
  "collection" : [
    {
      "fruit": "__fruit_type__",
    "clothings":{
      "item": "__clothing_type__}"
    }
  }, 
  {
    "fitness": "__fitness_equipment__",
    "mindfulness": "app called __meditation_app__"
  }
]
}
```

```
values.js
```

```
{
    "clothing_type": "winter",
   "fruit_type": "apple",
   "fitness_equipment": "treadmill",
   "meditation_app": "calm"
}
```

`replace.js`

```
const fs = require("fs").promises;

async function dataReader(filePath, data) {
  const result = await fs.readFile(filePath);
  try {
    return JSON.parse(result);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
//read values
async () => {
  const value = await dataReader("./values.json");
  const clothing_type = value.clothing_type;
  const fruit_type = value.fruit_type;
  const fitness_equipment = value.fitness_equipment;
  const meditation_app = value.meditation_app;

  //read collection.json
  const data = await jsonReader("./collections.json");

  //replace tokens in `collection.js` with `values.js`
};
```

Comment: The code reads the values file. Why doesn't it also read the collection file?

Comment: Also, the collection json won't parse.  Missing commas.

Comment: @danh It reads the collection file now. Do you have any idea or suggestions on how i can solve my qyestion?

Comment: why roll your own code. just use a templating engine? (ejs, handlerbars, nunjucks, etc. they'll all happily perfect this trick for you)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans the project requires me to iterate through the objects and replace those values using `string.replace() Method`

Comment: If this is homework, please remember to make that explicit in the post itself, because homework problems generally have fairly artificial homework solutions, rather than solutions you'd use if this is for your job or personal project and you need good code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## USING REGEX !!

- Now you have a collection.json (like a template) file.
- And values.json (a filler for the template), which has a set of values that will be placed in the template (collection.json).
- We assume that keys of values.json file are the fillers in collection.json
- if a key in values.json is `clothing_type` then the placeholder is `__clothing_type__`
- We can now iterate through the keys of values.json and look for a match in the collection.json with two underscores in the prefix and suffix

```js
///json will be parsed after filling the value
/// for this example i'll store the both the json files in varaible
const collections = `{
  "collection" : [
    {
      "fruit": "__fruit_type__",
    "clothings":{
      "item": "__clothing_type__}"
    }
  }, 
  {
    "fitness": "__fitness_equipment__",
    "mindfulness": "app called __meditation_app__"
  }
]
}`

/// naming the values.json as fillers as this may confuse with key,values in object
const fillers = `{
    "clothing_type": "winter",
   "fruit_type": "apple",
   "fitness_equipment": "treadmill",
   "meditation_app": "calm"
}`

function replaceFiller(template_collections,fillers){
    /// to loop through the keys of fillers or values.json we have parse this fisrt
    const fillersObj =JSON.parse(fillers);
    console.log(fillersObj);
    //// we dont want to modify the argument varaible "template_collection"
    /// so we will use a variable to store the template collection 
    /// and mutate them arbitrarily
    let resultJson = template_collections;

    
    /// looping through the keys of fillersObj
        for(let fillerKey of Object.keys(fillersObj)){
            /// here the filler key will be "clothing_type" ,"fruit_type" on every iteration
            // findig a match for the current key(fillerKey) with underscores in the collections.json and replacing them with the current keys value in fillersObj
            resultJson = resultJson.replace(`__${fillerKey}__`,fillersObj[fillerKey]);
            console.log(fillerKey,fillersObj[fillerKey]);
        }
  return JSON.parse(resultJson);
}
console.log(replaceFiller(collections,fillers));
```

## Caveats

- Values. json folder should never consist of nested objects.
- I have also had the same task with nested objects as fillers; I had to write a lot of code to flatten the objects and then replace tokens.
- This code is fine for simple cases like this. If you are going to handle large objects, then use this library  [jsonpath_object_transform](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath-object-transform)